# Heroku Can't Find View

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

This is a node app and the app is being loaded with node app.js. Locally, this is working fine. When I post this to heroku, it can't find the view "templates/views/home".

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because it was in a sails app. Sails only exposes views that are located in the /templates folder. My view was not in there so locally it could be seen but on heroku, only the /templates folder was made public.

Moved my views in there and it all worked.